# Atribute error on a suposedly working example code

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-re

I'm trying this solution from [Cookbooks](http://lascam.facom.ufu.br:8080/cookbooks/cookbook.jsp?api=beautifulsoup#ex4). The expected output is

> 4243456

but I keep getting an error

> Error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """
 <div class="heading-dom view">
     <script type="application/javascript">
        window.realty = {"user_id":4243456};
        <!--window.agency = < %- JSON.stringify(agency) % >;-->
        <!--window.agency = < %- JSON.stringify({}) % >-->
     </script>
</div>"""

pattern = re.compile(r'\{"user_id"\s*:\s*(\d+)\}')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
script = soup.find("script", text=pattern)

print(pattern.search(script.text).group(1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `script` has no text within it. When I tried this:

```
print(script.text)
```

this was the output that I got:

```
''
```

I think that you are trying to convert the variable `script` from data type `bs4.element.Tag` to `str`. In order to do that, change your last line to this:

```
print(pattern.search(str(script)).group(1))
```

Output:

```
4243456
```

Here is the full code:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """
 <div class="heading-dom view">
     <script type="application/javascript">
        window.realty = {"user_id":4243456};
        <!--window.agency = < %- JSON.stringify(agency) % >;-->
        <!--window.agency = < %- JSON.stringify({}) % >-->
     </script>
</div>"""

pattern = re.compile(r'\{"user_id"\s*:\s*(\d+)\}')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
script = soup.find("script", text=pattern)

print(pattern.search(str(script)).group(1))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now! Could you give me an explanation though?